# Dojo 1.8 dnd modify data state of dnd items

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop

I have a dnd.source and a dnd.target. So user drags an item from the source and drops it on the target. I use custom creators because their view is different. Its dnd item is backed by a data object like this

{alpha:"alphaVal",
 beta:"betaVal",
 charlie:"charlieVal", 
 delta:"deltaVal"}

The dnd items on the source are displayed as a list but when dropped onto the target the custom creator creates a div with three input fields so that user can alter the state of alpha, beta, charlie.

I then use dojo on so that when the value changes on any of the fields to update the item's data state. For instance,

```
function( item, hint ) {

var node = domConstruct.create( 'div' );

 var alphaVal = new TextBox( {
    name : 'filterBy',
    value : item.filterBy,
    placeHolder : 'type in a value',
  } );
  domConstruct.place( alphaVal.domNode, node );

 on( filterValue, 'change', function() {
    item.alphaVal = alphaVal.get( 'value' );
    targetDnd.setItem( itemId ,  item);
  } );

return {
  'node' : node,
  'data' : item,
  'type' : hint
};
};
```

As you can see I am changing the data state that is backing that dnd item. My problem is that the dnd source is set to copyOnly so items still remain in the source when dragged onto the target. So when I change the underlying data state of the dnd item in the target it also changes the data state of the dnd item which is on the source. Hence any subsequent drags 'n' drops of the same item carries that state with it. How can I stop this from happening?

Regards, 
G

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found so far is to use dojo/_base/lang to clone the item and then modify and return that.

```
var clonedItem = lang.clone(item);

on( inputTextBox, 'change', function() {
  // update clonedItem
  // target.setItem(itemId, clonedItem);
});      
return {
"node" : node,
"data" : clonedItem,
"type" : hint
};
```

I was wondering if there is a way to set the source to pass a clone of the data item rather than the reference of item.